# WPF: Detect Image click only on non-transparent portion

Tags: wpf, image, wpf-controls

I have an `Image` control in WPF which contains an image with lots of transparent pixels. Right now, the `MouseDown` event on `Image` fires whenever I click within the full rectangular region of the `Image` control. I would like some way to detect if the mouse click occurred on a nontransparent portion of the image.

What would be the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Using the technique in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3592404/irregular-png-buttons-click-event-in-wpf/3594911#3594911) you can derive from `Image` to create an `OpaqueClickableImage` that only responds to hit-testing in sufficiently non-transparent areas of the image:

```
public class OpaqueClickableImage : Image
{
    protected override HitTestResult HitTestCore(PointHitTestParameters hitTestParameters)
    {
        var source = (BitmapSource)Source;

        // Get the pixel of the source that was hit
        var x = (int)(hitTestParameters.HitPoint.X / ActualWidth * source.PixelWidth);
        var y = (int)(hitTestParameters.HitPoint.Y / ActualHeight * source.PixelHeight);

        // Copy the single pixel into a new byte array representing RGBA
        var pixel = new byte[4];
        source.CopyPixels(new Int32Rect(x, y, 1, 1), pixel, 4, 0);

        // Check the alpha (transparency) of the pixel
        // - threshold can be adjusted from 0 to 255
        if (pixel[3] < 10)
            return null;

        return new PointHitTestResult(this, hitTestParameters.HitPoint);
    }
}
```

after adding this class, just use it like a regular image:

```
<utils:OpaqueClickableImage Name="image" Source="http://entropymine.com/jason/testbed/pngtrans/rgb8_t_bk.png" Stretch="None"/>
```

Comment: Thanks! This works perfectly. I must have missed that other post.

Comment: I've actually seen this fail because `x` or `y` will be outside the the `PixelWidth` or `PixelHeight` of the `source`. Could either round down the calculation, or say, if `x>= PixelWidth: x = PixelWidth`

Comment: `CopyPixels` throws `System.ArgumentException` (out of bounds). What's the problem?

Answer (score 4):

```cs
public class OpaqueClickableImage : Image
{
    protected override HitTestResult HitTestCore(PointHitTestParameters hitTestParameters)
    {
        var source = (BitmapSource)Source;
        var x = (int)(hitTestParameters.HitPoint.X / ActualWidth * source.PixelWidth);
        var y = (int)(hitTestParameters.HitPoint.Y / ActualHeight * source.PixelHeight);
        if (x == source.PixelWidth)
            x--;
        if (y == source.PixelHeight)
            y--;

        var pixels = new byte[4];
        source.CopyPixels(new Int32Rect(x, y, 1, 1), pixels, 4, 0);
        
        return (pixels[3] < 1) ? null : new PointHitTestResult(this, hitTestParameters.HitPoint);
    }
}
```