# WPF Command Not Firing on Image Button Click

Tags: c#, wpf, image, binding

I am trying to make a Player (sort of) control. I have a Usercontrol for button already available 
(company controls). I am trying to give my button the shape of the Image I add into its content.

The problem is when i remove the template styling (which is to fit my button bounds according to image bounds) , I am not able to fire the ToolBarCommand associated when i try to click the button. Essentially, I am not able to Click the Button itself.

Goggling about this wasn't much help , I tried to `IsHitTestVisible="False"` to the Image - but that also didn't help.

Following is my code :

```
                <my:NewButton  Command="{Binding ToolBarCommand}" CommandParameter="Play">
                    <my:NewButton.Style>
                        <Style>
                            <Setter Property="my:NewButton.Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type my:NewButton}">
                                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment=" TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </my:NewButton.Style>
                    <my:NewButton.Content>
                        <Image Source="{Binding PlayState}" IsHitTestVisible="False" />
                    </my:NewButton.Content>
                </my:NewButton>
```

Any help is much appreciated.
P.S: VS2012 , .net 4.0

Comment: What is your DataContext?

Comment: @user1064519 : DataContext is a ViewModel Class for this View.
Also if I remove this Image tag and let it be a normal button then -every thing works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some non-null color and hit test visible pixels in the visual tree of the button for it to have hit test visibility.

You deliberately set `IsHitTestVisible="False"` on the image. If you remove it, it should work and if the image has transparent pixels - these will not "feel" the click.

If you have to have `IsHitTestVisible="False"` on the image, then in control template:

```
<Border Background="Transparent">
    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment=" TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
</Border>
```

The border will be the one that "feels" mouse clicks.

You can even set `Padding` on the button and have a bigger hit test area than the image.

Comment: Hi @XAMeLi , 
I believe as rightly pointed out be @nmclean , the problem is somewhere within my `NewButton` class.

Your code works fine with normal button.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The appearance of a control should completely changes when you apply `ControlTemplate` feature. `ContentPresent` is one of the easy way to inherit the button features to image control. `IsHitTestVisible=False` makes Image control to not fire the click event. Could you please try the below snippet

```
<my:NewButton  Command="{Binding ToolBarCommand}" CommandParameter="Play">
   <my:NewButton.Template>
       <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type my:NewButton}">
           <StackPanel>
               <Image Source="{Binding PlayState}"/>
               <ContentPresenter/>
           </StackPanel>
       </ControlTemplate>
   </my:NewButton.Template>
</my:NewButton>
```

Comment: Hi @Vimal , I tried implementing the code.
But it still doesn't allow me to click on the Button ( or here the visible Image ).

Answer (score 0):

If you set `IsHitTestVisible="False"` on the Image, the button will not be clickable unless there is something else "behind" it to see the click (like the transparent Border in XAMeLi's answer). But with IsHitTestVisible true (the default), it should be. In the following example, the Click event is fired, even if the image is transparent:

```
<Button Click="Button_Click">
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
            <ContentPresenter RecognizesAccessKey="True" />
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
    <Image Source="..." />
</Button>
```

So if this does not work for you, I think there must be something odd happening in your `NewButton` class.

If I understand correctly, you want to make the clickable area of the button defined by the non-transparent areas of an image.

Setting `IsHitTestVisible` makes the entire image element unclickable, not just the transparent area. The only way this would help you is if you had a transparent shape behind the image to capture the clicks.

As for using the image itself, I don't think WPF has any built-in support for it. You can define the shape of an entire *window* this way using [Window.AllowsTransparency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.allowstransparency.aspx), but that won't help you here.

You will need to implement hit-testing manually by overriding [HitTestCore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms608859.aspx) on the image element you want to be shaped. There is an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4800597/wpf-detect-image-click-only-on-non-transparent-portion) of how you might do that.

Comment: Hi @nmclean, 
I believe as you rightly pointed out, the problem is somewhere within my `NewButton` class.
Thanks for explaining about `IsHitTestVisible="False"`and Transarency features - it will be of much help.
Thanks!